# How do I track the frequency in this list?

Tags: python

I want to figure out how I can track the frequency of the numbers in the list that the user inputs. What I mean is: let's say someone input 45 twice, 52 three times, and 22 one time, the code would print out something like "Frequency: 45-2, 52-3, and 22-1". The other codes that ask this question are for lists that are already created in the code, but this one is different because the user is adding on to the list.

```
import sys

print ("After inputting this data, the sum, average, maximum and minimum 
number will be printed")

temperatureList = list()

weather=int(input("Enter the amount of days that you are looking at for 
the weather:"))

print("Enter the high temperature for those next days: ")

for i in range(int(weather)):
   k=int(input(""))
   temperatureList.append(int(k))
sm=sum(temperatureList)
avg=sm/weather
print("SUM = ",sm)
print("AVERAGE = ",avg)

temperatureList.sort()
print("This is the numbers from low to high", temperatureList)
print("Maximum number in the list is:", max(temperatureList), "and the 
minimum number is: ", min(temperatureList))

while True:
   action = int(input("Input add if you want to add to the list again. Or 
remove if you want to remove from the list, or end if you want to end this 
program"))

   if action == add:
      print("Enter what you want to be added ")
      add = int(input(""))
      temperatureList.append(add)
      print(temperatureList)
      sm = sum(temperatureList)
      avg = sm / weather
      print("SUM = ", sm)
      print("AVERAGE = ", avg)
      temperatureList.sort()
      print("This is the numbers from low to high", temperatureList)

   elif action == remove:
      if len(temperatureList) > 1:
         del temperatureList[-1]
         print(temperatureList)
         sm = sum(temperatureList)
         avg = sm / weather
         print("SUM = ", sm)
         print("AVERAGE = ", avg)

  else:
     print("Everything removed from the list")

   elif action == end:
      sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need what is known as a *histogram*. You can create one using a Python dictionary; use the answers you get as keys to the dictionary, and the answer counts as the corresponding values. Whenever you get an answer from the user, check if the dictionary already has an entry for that answer. If not, set the value to one. If the key exists, get the count, increase it by one, and store the new count. You can then print the dictionary (or some representation of it) before you start another loop round.

If you're not familiar with Python dictionaries, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) first.

Comment: It might be better to use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which is a specialized `dict` subclass, to do this.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good example of this problem on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-the-frequencies-in-a-list-using-dictionary-in-python/). Reading this will help you to solve your problem.

Here is the Python code they present for the solution:

```
# Python program to count the frequency of  
# elements in a list using a dictionary 

def CountFrequency(my_list): 

    # Creating an empty dictionary  
    freq = {} 
    for item in my_list: 
        if (item in freq): 
            freq[item] += 1
        else: 
            freq[item] = 1

    for key, value in freq.items(): 
        print ("% d : % d"%(key, value)) 

# Driver function 
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    my_list =[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2] 

    CountFrequency(my_list)
```

This simply iterates over the list, using each distinct element of the list as a key into a dictionary and storing the corresponding count of that key as a value.

It has a time complexity of O(n), where n is the length of the list, since it iterates over every value in the list.